Commuting normal operators and simultaneously diagonalizable
Let $T, S$ are two commuting normal operators on Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Does the following hold $$TS=\int_{\sigma(T)\times\sigma(S)}\lambda\mu d(E_{T}\otimes E_{S})?$$ where $E_{T}, E_{S}$ are spectral measures corresponding to $T, S$ respectively and $E_T\otimes E_S$ is a product measure.
Comments: Since $T, S$ are commutative normal, $TS$ is normal. I was first trying to see whether $E_{ST}=E_{T}\otimes E_{S}$? It is not yet clear to me.
Your comments are welcome. Thanks in advance.

I'm a bit rusty in these sorts of calculations, but I'd suspect so. Since the operators commute, the $C^*$ algebra they generate is commutative, and hence isomorphic to an algebra of continuous functions. So you just need to check that this identity holds on polynomials in two variables, and then I think that this is just Fubini. There are of course details to fill in (that's the part where I'm rusty), but I think this is the general argument.

Technically, $E_T\otimes E_S$ is a measure on (a subset of) $\mathbb C^2)$, while $E_{TS}$ is a measure on (a subset of) $\mathbb C$. So they cannot really be the same. But the first displayed equation holds anyway. You can find the proof in Schmüdgen's book for example.

The gist of the argument is that you can consider the joint continuous functional calculus, $C(\sigma(T) \times \sigma(S)) \to B(\mathcal{H})$, $f \otimes g \mapsto f(T)g(S)$. Then $E_T \otimes E_S$ is the spectral measure associated to that, and the result follows.
